# When a join duplicates columns _x _y how can I make them alternate by column rather than seperate by sheet?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

When I join 2 sheets using pandas and they have the same name for columns.  It will have Column a_x and column a_y etc. All of the _x's will be at the start of the sheet and all of the _Y's at the second stage.  Is there a way that I can alternate them e.g Column_x Column_y Column1_x Column1_y (rather than Column_x Column1_x Column2_x....)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can `sort` your columns then use that so set the output order:

```py
# cols = ["Column_x", "Column1_x", "Column2_x", "Column_y", "Column1_y", "Column2_y"]
cols = df.columns
cols.sort()
print(cols)
# ['Column1_x', 'Column1_y', 'Column2_x', 'Column2_y', 'Column_x', 'Column_y']

# Set output order
df.to_excel(..., columns=cols)
```